# Differential Equation Separation of Variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I separate the variables (as I assume will work for this equation) in the following equation:

> $yln(x) \frac {dx}{dy} = (\frac {y+1}{x})^{2}$

I am struggling with getting $x$ out of the term $ (\frac {y+1}{x})^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
y \ln x \dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy} &=& \left(\dfrac{y+1}x\right)^2 \\
x^2\ln x \dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy} &=& \dfrac{(y+1)^2}y \\
\displaystyle \int x^2\ln x \dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy} \ \mathrm dy &=& \displaystyle \int \dfrac{(y+1)^2}y \ \mathrm dy \\
\displaystyle \int x^2\ln x \ \mathrm dx &=& \displaystyle \int \dfrac{(y+1)^2}y \ \mathrm dy \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\frac{y+1}{x}\right)^2=\frac{(y+1)^2}{x^2}$$